# Baked normal map comes out transparent

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, baking

Blender 2.79
I'm trying to follow a Cycles workflow in baking out normals from a high poly mesh to low. Instead of a purple image with rainbow detail I'm getting nuthin.

1. I've checked both meshes' normals. They're all facing the right way.
2. A 2048 image was created for the normal bake and selected in the materials editor. It's not hooked up, but that shouldn't matter - so long as it's selected and targeted.
3. No modifiers are on either mesh. No subsurfs, nuthin.
4. Ray distance only seems to work on 0. Anything higher and the result is as the image shows.

What are your best guesses? I've had this happen before, and I found starting over again worked. I don't want to have to keep re-starting models.

[image: 2-frame GIF showing ray change. Click to expand]

[image]

Comment: Could you include a testing file with the problem shown on blend-exchange? I see this problem gets asked last time but I couldn't reproduce it

Comment: It's most definitely the ray distance. Try setting it to 1. Otherwise it's hard to tell without the file.

Comment: I don't get how it even works for you as it just shuts down for me when baking, but you disabled rendering surfaces for the render layer which objects are on. Though I've no idea how is this related with transparent normal maps working on nearly 0 ray distance only - this isn't that clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 2: FIX

Ok After some crazy amount of testing I found the culprit :D
[image: Check Use Suface]

In the render layer section, you have to check in EVERY render layer "use Surfaces".
If unchecked, you will get this strange transparent section in GPU Mode.
And in CPU mode it will even cause a crash to desktop.

In my opinion this crash is even worth a bug report.

Comment: Tried that - no joy. Just get different shaped transparent hole. Cage doesn't work - I get a error, that the two objects must have the same number of faces... which is kinda silly.

Comment: Amending last comment: Tried cage (properly this time, I think): still no joy.

Comment: then, have you checked if all your normals are pointing in the same direction?

Comment: 3. I've checked both meshes' normals. They're all facing the right way. (That is, all normals are radiating outwards from faces.)

Comment: Do you mind sharing your mesh? Then I can try to find the issue

Comment: Did you first select the high poly and then the low poly mesh?

Comment: Done, and Yes, respectively.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: Thanks Monasend :) Marked up your answer, but haven't called it correct because... Well, no offense, but you're effectively starting with a fresh file, which isn't a solve. If this keeps happening then there's some kind of bug, undetected corruption or weirdness I'm not aware of that will keep happening.

Comment: Ok I found the issue !

Comment: omg.... OMG! I'll try and duplicate this when I get back home. Marked your response right anyway cos I appreciate the effort :) It's kinda replacing one mystery with another: how did that box get unchecked? Is there a kbd shortcut I accidentally used, cos I don't recall deliberately unchecking that box!

Answer (score 1):

(Monatsend found a key part of the issue. I'm just adding this simple scene file you can test things with, and a link to a video that explains the bug... Because there's more to it.)

Baking Normals in Cycles successfully requires users to check several things in different areas. Basically, baking normals is a hack, rather than a workflow, so you have to stay on your toes.

Monatsend's right: 'Use Surfaces' needs to be checked, or normals can't be baked. **However, if you accidentally create a 'transparent normal' image, you can't go back from that. Something breaks. You'll need to restart Blender.**

Link to an explanatory video: https://vimeo.com/261681317

Normal Cube.blend: [image]